# Get Place Name with Reverse Geocoding Google Map API

Tags: c#, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am using [Google Maps API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters)  for reverse geo-coding by giving it the latitude and longitude. It is giving me the street address or other kind of short address.

What I want is the Business name or Place name of exact location.

I have tried to do this with [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) but it is asking for Type or Keyword to search for. While I don't have any specific type to search. I want just name.

Like this is Doctor's hospital & medical center. How can I get this name, I have Lat and Long for this place only.

[image: Sample image from google]

Comment: Did you see example 1 & 2?  My preference is to use the XML (not json) string and then extract info from xml.

Comment: I dont think it matters that we use either json or xml.
and Please give the lnks to example 1 & 2.

Comment: The first link is showing Error 404. Can you share some code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: No. Reverse Geocoding is not designed to do that. It is about turning geo coordinates into human-readable addresses. Two APIs that will allow to do that are the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) within the Javascript API and the [Places API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Comment: Do a search in your 2nd  link for example 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

With only Latitude and Longitude you can perform a search request, but it will take all places near these coordinates.
You can do it with:

[**Place Search**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&key=YOURAPIKEY

In the response, you will see all the places names (like your doctors hospital).

Example:
[image]

I recommend you to redesign the goal of your code, because the place identified by the coordinates depends a lot on their precision.

For example, latitude 45.35469190000001 is different from latitude 45.3547.
How can an api guess the place that will be in approximate coordinates?

The response is that Google don't use coordinates to uniquely identify a place,
but it uses Place Ids.

So your choice is:

- Use Place search to find all places nearby your coordinates.

or

- Redesign your code, in order to identify a place uniquely by place ids.

Comment: I have tried this as well. But I don't need all the other buildings around. I just need the building having the lat long. And I am getting lat long from Google maps. why is it not able to give me that name back.

Comment: Because Google don't identify a place(city, country, shop, road, etc) through its coordinates. But through place_id. To understand this, try to write rough coordinates on google maps site. You will find that they show you only a marker, without any informations. You said that you're getting lat lon from Google Maps. Maybe you can take places id as well?

Comment: yeah may be. I am onto it.
but google should have this kind of api to return every possible information about lat long.

Comment: They have every possible information, but only if the specific place id is provided.